# How to disable those dates (in jquery datepicker) which is stored in mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I want to disable those dates which is in mysql database. Actually every time It is very hard to change dates in javascript so I want to add future dates in mysql database and it will show those disable dates in jquery datepicker from mysql database.
I am trying this code but I am getting confused

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: +1,
    maxDate: "+3m",
        beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
        });
```

});

```
dateo = $("#datepicker").attr("value");  //need help here (1)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajaxdates.php",

 data: 'dateone='+mydate,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
              }
        });


var $myBadDates = new Array("#result", "2018-08-09");  // need help here (2)


function checkBadDates(mydate){             // need help here (3)


var $return=true;
var $returnclass ="available";
$checkdate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', mydate);
for(var i = 0; i < $myBadDates.length; i++)
    {    
       if($myBadDates[i] == $checkdate)
          {
        $return = false;
        $returnclass= "unavailable";
        }
    }
return [$return,$returnclass];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an idea like this one: sometime this may help you:

```js
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disableddates = ["31-07-2018", "12-06-2018", "12-08-2018", "22-08-2018"];


function checkBadDates(date) {
  var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
  return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}

$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
```

If you able to set an ajax code to pull date to disable from DB, then:

```
var disableddates = [];
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "my_ajax_stuff.php" ,
   async: false, // Please add this line
   success: function(response) {
       disableddates = ["31-07-2018", "12-06-2018", "12-08-2018", "22-08-2018"]; // this will be list of disabled dates from db
       $("#datepicker").datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: checkBadDates
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: This will work I know but I don't want to add dates in javascript. I want to pull dates from mysql database.
This 
Var disableddates = [ ] here I need to pull mysql database dates.
Please

Comment: Get the date from db using ajax add set it as a similar array, after that reload the datepicker.

Comment: How to add it in similar array.it is Confusing.
Please help

Comment: are you able to get dates using ajax. the dates obtained so can be pushed to create an array like above.

Comment: Yes I can . then what to do

Comment: Yes I can get date using ajax. Next how to use it as a variable of var disabledates?

Comment: So you created Days to be disabled as an array?

Comment: I have 3 dates in mysql database. I m pulling it by php. Then I m putting these in ajax then I dont know what to do. Can u help?

Comment: set `disableddates` as that it can de accessed in the `checkBadDates` function